# Can we Count API HIT's using Throttling in Django DRF

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, throttling

I created some API using Djanago- DRF.
Now, I want to count the API HIT's through Throttling and if total count is reached 500 user will deative mode(is_active = False)

So, any idea how can do this through throtting.
if any other approach is there plz suggest me